# Load file from ViewBag?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Razor page where I load some data (not in a form) and one of those "fields" is a file.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <label>Upload Construction Map:</label>
   <br />
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
         <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
            Browse @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ShapeFileModel.ConstructFile, new { id = "fu-construct", type = "file", accept = ".pdf" })
         </span>
      </span>
      @{
         if (fileId != "")
         {
            int theId = int.Parse(fileId);
            CrossCData.DAL.File fileMap = (from f in dbCrossingsCloud.Files
                                           where f.Id == theId
                                           select f).SingleOrDefault();
      <input type="text" id="txtPathConstruct" class="form-control" value="@fileMap.FileName" contenteditable="false" readonly />
         }
         else
         {
      <input type="text" id="txtPathConstruct" class="form-control" value="" contenteditable="false" readonly />
         }
      }
   </div>
</div>
```

I return in ViewBag.fileId the Id of the file, then I get the details of the file which is stored in a file system (not database). So... file location (folder path) and file name.

Is it possible to use IO in Razor to load a file to the input? and to a javascript variable?

Any help will be appreciated!

**Javascript I use to manage the file**

```
$("#fu-construct").fileupload({
        url: 'UploadConstructFile',
        dataType: 'json',
        // File was added
        add: function (e, data) {
            var fileExtension = ['pdf'];  // Valid file extensions
            if ($.inArray($("#txtPathConstruct").val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
                swal("Error", "Only PDF files are allowed. Please select a file in PDF format.", "error");
                $("#txtPathConstruct").val("No file chosen...");
                constructData = null;
            } else {
                constructData = data;
            }
        },
        // UploadConstructFile is done
        done: function (event, data) {
            fileId = data.result.fileId;
            if (projectCompany == "" || typeof projectCompany == 'undefined') {
                swal("Error", "Please enter a requesting company", "error");
            }
            else if (projectName == "" || typeof projectName == 'undefined') {
                swal("Error", "Please enter a project name.", "error");
            }
            else if (projectType == "" || typeof projectType == 'undefined') {
                swal("Error", "Please select a project type.", "error");
            }
            else {
                post('Audit', 'post', JSON.stringify(myDataTable.rows().data().toArray()), fileId, projectCompany, projectName, projectType, projectFileNumber, projectAFECC);
            }
        },
        fail: function (event, data) {
            alert("Error uploading the file.");
            $("#txtPathShape").val("No file chosen...");
        }
    });

    $("#construct-upload").on('click', function () {
        if (constructData) {
            constructData.submit();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: It is generally considered bad practice to pass data through ViewBag. I'd suggest using a strongly typed view model and HttpPostedFile class as a field.

Comment: I re-read your question. Are you trying to serve the file from your server or have the user upload the file to the server? If its the later (*client sending file to server*) my answer is not correct but I can rewrite it with my recommendation.

Comment: The user uploads the file and once they submit in Add.cshtml I save it to the server, then from the Audit.cshtml file the user wants to go back and fix the info but I need to load the file again to `constructData` in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use IO in Razor to load a file to the input? and to a javascript variable?

Razor creates a text stream that will be sent to the browser. The content of the text is (usually) expected to be html. If you wanted to include a file you would have to write it to a field (maybe input type hidden) as base64 for binary files or plain text for text files. I would **avoid this approach and not include file content in the view itself**.

A better option would be to create a `MVC` controller method or a `Web API` method that can serve up a file based on a unique identifier (*your mentioned File Id is probably perfect*). You would then include the identifier in your Razor output (*instead of the content of the file*) and could retrieve it with an AJAX call from JavaScript when you need it.